# iOS7 - device restaring when copying 500 records to eventstore with Commit=YES

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, eventkit

The below code will work fine with 500 records, we are batching the operation and commit the eventstore after adding 500 records.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
for(int i=0 ; i< 500 ; i++){

    EKCalendar *calendarDef = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    [event setCalendar:calendarDef];

    //set values to this event. like title, notes, startDate, endDate, location
    event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testno-%i", i];
    event.startDate = [NSDate date];
    event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:180];


    NSError *err1 = nil;
    BOOL isStoredd = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:NO error:&err1];

    NSLog(@"item %i", i);
    if(isStoredd){

        NSLog(@"stored");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"event saved error = %@",err1);

    }

}
[eventStore commit:NULL];
```

Suppose we need the eventidentifier of each copying event record for future modifications, then we should commit each record to get the identifier . But when doing this we are getting memory warning and device is restarting.. Below is the sample code:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
for(int i=0 ; i< 500 ; i++){

    NSString *eventIde = nil;
    EKCalendar *calendarDef = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    [event setCalendar:calendarDef];

    //set values to this event. like title, notes, startDate, endDate, location
    event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testno-%i", i];
    event.startDate = [NSDate date];
    event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:180];


    NSError *err1 = nil;
    BOOL isStoredd = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err1];

    NSLog(@"item %i", i);
    if(isStoredd){

        eventIde = event.eventIdentifier;
        //storing the eventIde to application's database to modify/delete the event later.
        NSLog(@"stored identifier %@", eventIde);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"event saved error = %@",err1);

    }

}
```

We need the eventidentifier for future modifications(update/delete), So looking for a way to insert 500+ records into eventstore by gettng its eventidentifier. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue? If YES could you please provide the solution